# Hangfire create cron job in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am new in hangfire. I want to create a regular cron job which triggers in every 30 minutes. In documentation i couldn't find a good example. For example this is  my method :

```
public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (EfDbContext _db = new EfDbContext())
        {
            _db.Jobs.add(new CronJob
            {
               status = "job fires",
               date = DateTime.Now
            });
        }
    }
```

And i want to trigger it in every 30 minutes. How to do it in asp.net mvc? (using hangfire).

Comment: And where should i write RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate() this method. In controller, in global.asax or where?

Comment: It depends on what triggers this recurring job. If you just want to execute every 30 minutes you can add that to your Startup or Application_Start in Global.asax.

Comment: It works thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

just make a console application which is trigger your controller/action , bind it  to Windows Task Schedule this is best and fast way to do it trust me.